# Phonegap camera crash on android 4.1.2, samsung galaxy s3, HTC

Tags: android, crash, cordova, camera

I think a lot of developers are familier with this problem of phonegap crashes/restarts after getting a picture from camera / library on android 4.1.2.

After many searches of many solutions I want to put some order into this problem and I wish you could help me understand what is the current solution. Note: the current stable phonegap version is 2.9.0.

1. Using fileURI and not dataURL, because the encoded base64 is too big for the DOM to handle.
2. Editing (not via phonegap build config.xml) the android manifest file and add the following line to every activity:

> ```
> android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:launchMode="singleTask".
> ```

1. Limit the resolution using targetWidth/targetHeight, because the image is to big which causes memory over load. and reducing quality..
2. Switch off the

> "Do not keep actitivies"

option in android settings.. which is ofcourse not a real solutions becaues we can't ask users to do that..

1. Again, editing the android manifest (with discarding phonegap build service) and add:

> ```
> android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
>
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
>
> <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
>
> <activity  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
> ```

1. Using an external camera plugin (not phonegap's):

links to all these solutions are here:
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap_camera_crash_on_android_4_1_2_samsung_galaxy_s3_htc

Now.. 
After this literature review.. Does anyone know which combination works? 
please help!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
You require the following to get this to work:
Make sure "uses-feature" tag appears after "application" tag.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>

<application 
......
```

I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks but I am using phonegap build.. I think there is no "<uses-feature.." there..